Setup Zigbee devices without hub
I have a zigbee curtain switch. This switch is connected to home assistant using a sonoff dongle. All is working perfectly fine.
Afaik, those switches can be configured (for example up or down duration) when using a Tuya hub (for that switch it is Tuya) and Tuya app.
Is there any way that I can configure my switches using my setup described above?
